# Findbugs sees child class' inherited fields and methods as Nonnull

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, package, findbugs

I want to apply the `@Nonnull` annotation to every field, parameter and method in a given package.

I have this annotation named *NotNullByDefault*:

```
@Documented
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault({
    ElementType.FIELD,
    ElementType.METHOD,
    ElementType.PARAMETER
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NotNullByDefault {
}
```

I now have two classes in two different packages:

Class *Parent* which has no annotations and I have *no control over*:

```
package com.parent;

public class Parent {
    protected Object parentField;

    protected Object parentMethod(Object parentParameter){
        return parentParameter;
    }
}
```

then we have my class, *Child*:

```
package com.child;

public class Child extends Parent {
    private Object childField;

    public Object childMethod(Object childParameter){
        return childParameter;
    }
}
```

Now by applying my annotation on *Child* with:

```
// package-info.java in com.child
@NotNullByDefault
package com.child;
```

I expect findbugs to *see* *Child* like so:

```
package com.child;

public class Child extends Parent {

    @NotNullByDefault
    private Object childField;

    protected Object parentField;

    @NotNullByDefault
    public Object childMethod(@NotNullByDefault Object childParameter){
        return childParameter;
    }

    protected Object parentMethod(Object parentParameter){
        return parentParameter;
    }
}
```

Instead, it sees it like this:

```
package com.child;

public class Child extends Parent {

    @NotNullByDefault
    private Object childField;

    @NotNullByDefault
    protected Object parentField;

    @NotNullByDefault
    public Object childMethod(@NotNullByDefault Object childParameter){
        return childParameter;
    }

    @NotNullByDefault
    protected Object parentMethod(@NotNullByDefault Object parentParameter){
        return parentParameter;
    }
}
```

I know that because I get a redundant null check warning saying that the nullity checks that I do to fields and methods of the parent class are not needed.

How can I prevent non-annotated inherited methods and fields to not be seen as annotated by findbugs?